# Dojo JsonRestStore with array not at root-level of JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo, jsonschema

Is there a way to configure a JsonRestStore to work with an existing web service that returns an array of objects which is **not** at the root-level of the JSON response?

My JSON response is currently similar to this:

```
{
    message: "",
    success: true,
    data: [
        { name: "Bugs Bunny", id: 1 },
        { name: "Daffy Duck", id: 2 }
    ],
    total: 2
}
```

I need to tell the JsonRestStore that it will find the rows under "data", but I can't see a way to do this from looking at the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/data/JsonRestStore). Schema seems like a possibility but I can't make sense of it through the docs (or what I find in Google).

My web services return data in a format expected by stores in Ext JS, but I can't refactor years worth of web services now (dealing with pagination via HTTP headers instead of query string values will probably be fun, too, but that's a problem for another day).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's only barely called out in the API docs, there is an internal method in `dojox/data/JsonRestStore` named `_processResults` that happens to be easily overridable for this purpose.  It receives the data returned by the service and the original Deferred from the request, and is expected to return an object containing `items` and `totalCount`.

Based on your data above, something like this ought to work:

```
var CustomRestStore = declare(JsonRestStore, {
    _processResults: function (results) {
        return {
            items: results.data,
            totalCount: results.total
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: That certainly looks like what I want, thank you. My dojo evaluation hasn't proceeded much, unfortunately, but it's still at the top of my list of alternatives should I decide bin Ext JS. I may rig up a test case using your code just to see it work and improve my confidence in dojo. Thanks again

Comment: I've got a bit of time on my hands so I'm trying this again. I'm working with the dijit.form.FilteringSelect 1.10 reference guide. I implemented your custom solution (which seems to work) but I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" errors in digit/form/_AutoCompleterMixin.js at line 187 (about a second after typing something and seeing results appear below the combobox). If I put my sample back to the plain JsonRestStore I get no errors (and no data, of course). Any ideas based on these scant details? Thanks.

Comment: If I set searchAttr on my FilteringSelect combobox to the same as the labelAttr value, then it's fine. However, my service expects "query=" for the searchAttr, not "whateverFieldName=". I'll post a new question, I think (since it's not related to my original inquiry). thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The idea with dojo/store is that reference stores are provided, but they are intended to be customized to match whatever data format you want. For example, https://github.com/sitepen/dojo-smore has a few additional stores (e.g. one that handles Csv data). These stores provide good examples for how to handle data that is offered under a different structure.

There's also the new dstore project, http://dstorejs.io/ , which is going to eventually replace dojo/store in Dojo 2, but works today against Dojo 1.x. This might be easier for creating a custom store to match your data structure.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out (I wasn't aware of it). However, I've just realised that SitePen's yearly support package costs $12,500, so I may have to shelve ideas of switching to Dojo for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Alas, after looking through the dstore docs, I can see no information on how to get data from a web service that doesn't adhere to dojo's expectations: https://github.com/SitePen/dstore#dstore

Comment: For a dojo/store example, take a look at how the OData store works, which delivers data much differently: https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/store/OData.js

Comment: Regarding support, SitePen's support isn't just support for Dojo, it's hands-on help for your code as well. You can always ask for a smaller plan for a year (send me an email), but the support as intended is really to give more hands-on help, and to contribute more standard help (e.g. answering standard questions) in public forums like this and the dojo-interest mailing list, rather than requiring you to pay for that, etc.